# Error message is not shown on user page in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem showing message to a user after exception is thrown.
What I am doing is trying to log in as unexciting user. Server in that case returns me 401 and message "Wrong username and password combination"

In my controller I am preforming this:

```
class LoginOnlineUserController {
    constructor($state, AuthenticationService, LoginOnlineUserService) {
        this.$state = $state;
        this.AuthenticationService = AuthenticationService;
        this.LoginOnlineUserService = LoginOnlineUserService;

        this.username = null;
        this.password = null;
    }

    login() {
        let self = this;

        this.LoginOnlineUserService.login({
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        }).then(function(data) {
            self.AuthenticationService.login(data.jwtToken);

            if(self.AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
                self.$state.go("hrTesting");
            }
        }).catch(function(msg) {
            //alert(msg.data);
            self.error = msg.data;
        });
    }
}

export default LoginOnlineUserController;
```

If function `isAuthenticated()` is preformed well, and token is in response, than give that token to a user.
If exception happens than go in catch block and write a message on clients page.

I am using ng-if for this:

```
<div ng-if="self.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{self.error}}</div>
```

But message is never shown. When I try to alert the message from exception I can see it clearly, but error message do not exists on user page. 
Does anybody sees what I am doing wrongly here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you are binding your controller like `ng-controller="MyCtrl as self"`? that's critical for using inside of template.